# Getting error - "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out" in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter 5.4.1, where I am using a HTTP request for Post API call. I am getting the error - "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out".

Keep-Alive is checked. Timeouts are also set to 60 Seconds. I am using single thread.

What is the solution to get raid of this?

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1936)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:476)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:673)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It's very difficult to try and give options with only a generic log output to look at. 
This might help you work through your problem though; [link](https://www.xtivia.com/blog/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors/)